# Ionic 3 search is not showing list after clearing search bar

Tags: angular, search, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Hello please help i'm trying to do search from list, The words are showing on the list but after clearing the search bar is not showing anything please help

Here is my home.html

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"[showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"></ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="eXplain()">
    {{ item.word }}
  </button>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and my home.ts is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

searchQuery: string = '';
  items:any;
  word:any;
  meaning:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  private http: Http, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public loading: LoadingController,public modalCtrl : ModalController) {

   this.initializeItems();

  }

 ngOnInit(){   

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

     let loader = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Processing please wait...',
      });

     loader.present().then(() => {

    this.http.post('**MY URL IS HERE**',options)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => {

     loader.dismiss()
    this.items=res.server_response;

    console.log(this.items);
    });
    });
     }

initializeItems() {

 this.items;

  }

  getItems(ev) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the ev target
    var val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item: any) => {
        return (item.word.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**The words are showing on the list but after clearing the search bar is not showing anything please help**

Comment: @Golden Mashego you are not returning any items, if input value is empty, you should return all items

Comment: thanks for reply, i'm still new to ionic, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside ngOnInit when you received the response, deep copy it to one more variable:

```
this.initialItems = res.server_response;
this.items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialItems));
```

Don't call initializeItems in constructor, & update your initializeItems method to:

```
initializeItems() {
 this.items = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initialItems));
}
```

Keep all of your other code same.

Comment: its working like a charm :) thank you, you are the best @Shantanu